# ASP.NET 3.5 - Open a PDF directly from stream in pdf viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-reader, pdf-viewer

I'm working on a ASP.NET web forms C# 3.0 / .NET 3.5 project involving building some canned reports. One of the requirements of the project is to export to PDF format, and currently doing so to disk is working just fine. The question was raised, however, if it's possible to export the file to a stream and open it directly in the native viewer on the client, skipping entirely writing it to disk.

Anybody have any insight on how it might be done, if it's possible at all?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Convert the stream to a byte[] and BinaryWrite it directly to the HttpResponse.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Content-Disposition HTTP header. Something like

`Content-Disposition: inline; filename=myFile.pdf`

Also, the content type should be `application/pdf`

Comment: Thank you. But i want to open PDF file in PDF viewer by passing file stream. Does there any way to open it in PDF viewer? could you please suggest me any free PDF viewer which is able to read directly file stream?